# 'CheckpointLoadStatus' object has no attribute 'evaluate'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to save the weights of a tensorflow model so I can easily load in the weights and apply the evaluate function on new unseen data. Applying the save_model and load_model works, but I wanted to increase the speed of saving/loading models by only keeping the weights.

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,EarlyStopping
import tensorflow as tf
model1 = build_bi_lstm_model()
cp_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path+ '\\'+symbol+"\\"+str(submodel)+"\\w1",
                                                    save_weights_only=True,
                                                    verbose=1)
history1 = model1.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=20, batch_size=bat_size, verbose=1,validation_data=(dfc_val,dfc_val_y),shuffle=False,callbacks=[early_stop,cp_callback])
model1.save_weights(checkpoint_path+ '\\'+symbol+"\\"+str(submodel)+"\\w1") #=> Double saving the weights as a check
```

Applying model.evaluate does not give any problems after training and saving the weights of the model.

However when I try to load in the weights after training as follow:

```
model1 = build_bi_lstm_model()
model1=  model1.load_weights(checkpoint_path+ "\\"+symbol+"\\"+str(submodel)+"\\w1")
score = model1.evaluate(last_batch_dfc_test, last_batch_dfc_test_y,verbose=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
'CheckpointLoadStatus' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: do not assign the return value of load_weights to the model, nowhere that is required.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments above by Dr.Snoopy, not assigning a return value, but keeping it inline does the trick:

```
model1.load_weights(checkpoint_path+ "\\"+symbol+"\\"+str(submodel)+"\\w1")
```